# Rabin-Karp giving wrong answer with increasing power raise to p

Tags: c++, algorithm, rabin-karp

I have started learning string processing algorithms and wanted to implement the Rabin-Karp algorithm in C++. I have taken:

p = prime number larger than character set: 31
m = prime number for mod operations: 1e9+9

According to what I can find, there are multiple ways to implement the algorithm and I have tested two of them: increasing power as we go to higher index and decreasing power as we go to higher index.

For example on string S[0..n-1]

Let M1 = S[0]*p^0 + S[1]*p^1 + S[2]*p^2 + ... + S[n-1]*p^n-1

Let M2 = S[0]*p^n-1 + S[1]*p^n-2 + S[2]*p^n-3 ... + S[n-1]*p^0

I have implemented both the methods and could only get successful results using M2.

Code for M1:

```
int rabinKarpM1(string s, string t) {
    int a = (int)s.size(), b = (int)t.size();
    long long p = 31, m = 1e9+9;
    long long powTable[a] = {0};
    powTable[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        powTable[i] = powTable[i-1] * p % m;
    }

    long long hashS = 0, hashT = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        hashS = (hashS + (s[i] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[i] % m) % m;
        hashT = (hashT + (t[i] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[i] % m) % m;
    }

    if (hashS == hashT) {
        bool match = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (s[i] != t[i]) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i+a-1 < b; i++) {
        hashT = (hashT - (t[i] - 'a' + 1)) / p;
        hashT = hashT + (t[i+a] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[a-1] % m;
        hashT = hashT % m;
        if (hashS == hashT) {
            bool match = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < a+i+1; j++) {
                if (s[j-i-1] != t[j]) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (match) {
                return i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Code for M2:

```
int rabinKarpM2(string s, string t) {
    int a = (int)s.size(), b = (int)t.size();
    long long p = 31, m = 1e9+9;
    long long powTable[a] = {0};
    powTable[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        powTable[i] = powTable[i-1] * p % m;
    }

    long long hashS = 0, hashT = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        hashS = (hashS + (s[i] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[a-i-1] % m) % m;
        hashT = (hashT + (t[i] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[a-i-1] % m) % m;
    }

    if (hashS == hashT) {
        bool match = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (s[i] != t[i]) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i+a-1 < b; i++) {
        hashT = (hashT + m - (t[i] - 'a' + 1)*powTable[a-1] % m) % m * p;
        hashT = hashT + (t[i+a] - 'a' + 1) % m;
        hashT = hashT % m;
        if (hashS == hashT) {
            bool match = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < a+i+1; j++) {
                if (s[j-i-1] != t[j]) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (match) {
                return i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Test Input:
string s = foobarfoo
string t = barfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoo

I have got correct results on M2 but not on M1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on your first question! Could you elaborate on the expected result of the algorithm based on your input? This might help us identify the problem.